# Getting different value than the one in the inifile

Tags: file, delphi, ini

I've placed a custom entry in the win.ini file in the windows directory , called LoginCount under a custom [Login] section and increment it each time the main view is loaded. In the Form Create event I access the win.ini and check for its value and if it's reached 1000 I show a message. But a very weird thing has happened. After reaching 1000 I manually set its value back to 0. But it still shows 1000. I checked the path, in case the application refers to some other win.ini file somewhere in the system, but it's C:\Windows\win.ini. Here's the code:

```
procedure TfMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
     winIni: TIniFile; 
     windir_buf: array [0 .. 144] of Char;
     WINDIR: string;
     loginCount: integer;
  begin
   GetWindowsDirectory(windir_buf, sizeof(windir_buf));
   WINDIR := StrPas(windir_buf) + '\';

   ShowMessage(WINDIR+'win.ini');//Shows C:\Windows\win.ini

   winIni := TIniFile.Create(WINDIR + 'Win.ini');
   loginCount := winIni.ReadInteger('Login', 'LoginCount', 1);
   ShowMessage(IntToStr(loginCount));//Shows 1000 although it's 0 in the actual file.
  end;
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Apart from the problem, why do you use the `win.ini` file? Normal users should not have write access to the windows dir.

Comment: Windows 3.1 is over. It's time to move on. It's been time to move on for 20 years.

Comment: @SirRufo, you know, it's an old, very old application written by someone else. Now I need to fix the problem there. I don't want to bother wrting new code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to file system virtualization. You are running a virtualized process under Vista or later and don't have write access to the Windows directory.

There's no point debugging this. The Win.ini file has been deprecated for nearly 20 years. You should:

1. Add a manifest to suppress virtualization.
2. Ensure that you run with UAC enabled, and as standard user.
3. Store your file to an appropriate folder. Under the user profile is the obvious place. That makes it a per-user setting. For system-wide settings you store to the ProgramData folder.

If you simply cannot bring yourself to stop using Win.ini then you'll still need to add a manifest with the *requireAdministrator* option.

If you are going to use Win.ini (and I cannot express how much I abhor the fact you contemplate doing so) then you should use `GetProfileString` and `SetProfileString`. Since the file is shared you need to access it with functions that synchronize that access.

Comment: Then it means this should be fixed on its own by just restarting the computer?

Comment: I don't say that at all

Comment: You know, it's been nearly a decade I've been away from Delphi and I can understand how irritated you get by the fact that someone still uses ini files. But suddenly I found myself facing this odd problem that I was required to fix.

Comment: I'm not irritated. I'm just giving my opinion on the right thing to do. I frown on using Win.ini but I don't feel irritation. I've no problem with ini files, but Win.ini is no ordinary ini file.

Comment: @MikeJM, there is nothing irritating in ini files, it is a good format, but hiding something application-specific in system environment config was wrong from the beginning.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, yeah sure, it was. You know, many people tend to compromise security in favor of getting things fast and easy. They do this mostly as a result of being incompetent or being lazy. Now it seems the programmer who did that, did not care (or know) about the system file security and wanted to place the control point to somewhere that would be hard to find.